# Excel structured reference with variable name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, structured-references

I have a table `TABLE` and two cells `E1` and `E2`. The entry of `E1` is guaranteed to be a header of `TABLE`. I'd like to write a formula to check wether the entry of `E2` is contained in the table column `TABLE["content of E1"]`.

My current approach looks like this (and does not work):

`=COUNTIF(TABLE[E1]; E2)>0`

I think excel searches for `"E2"` in the table headers and does not find anything. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: Don't you want to search the headers, not E1?

Comment: @SJR Let's say E1 is "Name" and E2 is "Max". I'd like to check whether `TABLE[Name]` contains "Max".

Comment: You need to use INDIRECT formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the INDIRECT formula, eg:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("TABLE[" & E1 & "]"),E2)
```